# Navigation between Pages

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

This method is effective only for windows 8.0 :

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SamePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

is there another method with same functionality that is effective for 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), param);
```

Comment: i need to switch to the next page according to its name that is string not frame ("/SamePage.xaml")